# Combing two similar functions that show two hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a designer who dabbles in code from time to dime, really just to make small amendments.

I have some existing code that works in the following way:

- A text link (class 'one') appears on the page after a short delay
- When you click the link, a hidden div (class 'overlayone') is made visible and slides up to reveal content
- When you click an X (class 'close') in the corner, it closes the div.

I need to ad a second link on the page, called "two" that functions in the same way, but opens a different hidden div (called 'overlaytwo'). I'm, not sure how to append it to the existing code though. The current code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".one").addClass("active"), $("img").trigger("unveil")
}, 1e3), $("a.one").on("click", function() {
    $(".overlayone").addClass("active")
}), $(".close").on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".overlayone").removeClass("active")
    }, 400), setTimeout(function() {
        $(".close").removeClass("is-active")
    }, 1e3)
})
});
```

Comment: Make a function and pass selector string as argument

Comment: provide some html code and and @ Sojtin passing the selector will not work as `.close` of `.one` will close the `.two' also and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your point :|

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function setClassTimeout(class){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("." + class).addClass("active"), $("img").trigger("unveil")
    }, 1e3), $("a." + class).on("click", function() {
        $(".overlay" + class).addClass("active")
    }), $(".close").on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".overlay" + class).removeClass("active")
    }, 400), setTimeout(function() {
        $(".close").removeClass("is-active")
    }, 1e3)
    })
}

var array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    setClassTimeout(array[i]);
}

});
```

Comment: this wont work as `.close` of `.one` will close the `.two' also and vice versa
you have to also give unique id for each close button also in html

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is :

```
<div class="one"  > 
     <a href="#" class="one">One</a> 
</div> 


<div class="two"> 
    <a href="#" class="two">Two</a>     
</div> 

<div class="overlayone"> 
    <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close"> <span>toggle menu</span> </button> 
    <div class="content"> <p>Text content...One</p> </div>
</div> 
<div class="overlaytwo"> 
     <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close"> <span>toggle menu</span> </button> 
     <div class="content"> <p>Text content...Two</p> </div>
</div>
```

You will need to modify your html little bit . Find code below
There is code comment where there is change in code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Added class to link having class "two"
 setTimeout(function() {
  $(".one").addClass("active");
  $(".two").addClass("active");
  $("img").trigger("unveil")
 }, 1e3); 
 
  /*When link is clicked  custom attribute value of that link is  taken and based on that "active" class is added to overlay div*/
 $("a.links").on("click", function() {
  $('.'+$(this).data('overlay')).addClass("active")
 });

 $(".close").on("click", function() {
     var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
            // "Self" is clicked close  button and active class is removed  from parent of that button 
   $(self).parent().removeClass("active")
  }, 400);
  setTimeout(function() {
   $(self).removeClass("is-active")
  }, 1e3)
 });
});
```

```css
.active{
 display : block !important;
}

.overlayone,
.overlaytwo{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Add one custom attribute in anchor tag . Value of that attribute will be corresponding div.Also add class "links" to anchor tag-->
<div class="one"  > 
 <a href="#" class="one links"  data-overlay="overlayone">One</a> 
</div> 

<!--Add one custom attribute in anchor tag . Value of that attribute will be corresponding  div. Also add class "links" to anchor tag-->
<div class="two"> 
 <a href="#" class="two links"  data-overlay="overlaytwo">Two</a>  
</div> 

<div class="overlayone"> 
 <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close"> <span>toggle menu</span> </button> 
 <div class="content"> <p>Text content...One</p> </div>
</div>

<div class="overlaytwo"> 
    <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close"> <span>toggle menu</span> </button> 
  <div class="content"> <p>Text content...Two</p> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I have tried doing this, but it's not working and needs a rewrite of how the div structure and classes currently work - which is probably just beyond my skill set. Is there not a simpler way to integrate the second function and class ('overlaytwo') to the existing code I have?

Comment: Yes you can integrate class **overlaytwo** in current code but when number of links and overlay increase it will become messy to handle . Please  provide more details of your html code and how do you hide dives so that I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thats ok. There will not be any more than 3-4 links in the future I think. I keep trying to ad the html code here, but there is a word limit which prevents me?

Comment: <div class="two">
      <a href="#" class="two">Two</a>
    </div>
    
 <div class="one">
      <a href="#" class="one">One</a>
    </div>
  
    
 <div class="overlayone">
      <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close">
        <span>toggle menu</span>
      </button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Text content...</p>
  </div>
 
 <div class="overlaytwo">
      <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close">
        <span>toggle menu</span>
      </button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Text content...</p>
  </div>`

Comment: Gosh I feel so stupid. I've tried implementing this, but just can't get it working with the rest of may html code and css. I think I was just hoping for a simple few lines that could be aded to the original js to reference this second class and div.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I have not touched your HTML code that you have provided in one of your comment. I have just changed js . Make sure the way in which you hide and show elements are not conflicting here.This is not better solution as you have to maintain js code every time you add new link. My first answer is better.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".one,.two").addClass("active"),          
    $("img").trigger("unveil")
  }, 1e3),$("a.one,a.two").on("click", function(event) {
              if($(event.target).hasClass('one')){
                $(".overlayone").addClass("active");
           }else{
       $(".overlaytwo").addClass("active");
        }
    }), $(".close").on("click", function(event) {
        var self = this; 
           setTimeout(function() {  
             $(self).parent().removeClass("active")
           }, 400), setTimeout(function() {
             $(self).removeClass("is-active")
          }, 1e3)
    })
});
```

```css
.active{
  display : block !important;
}
 
.overlayone,
.overlaytwo,
a.one,
a.two{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="one"  > 
  <a href="#" class="one">One</a> 
</div> 

<div class="two"> 
  <a href="#" class="two" >Two</a>  
</div> 

<div class="overlayone"> 
  <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close"> <span>toggle menu</span> </button> 
  <div class="content"> <p>Text content...One</p> </div>
</div>

<div class="overlaytwo"> 
  <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx close"> <span>toggle menu</span> </button> 
  <div class="content"> <p>Text content...Two</p> </div>
</div>
```